# Add a test case to TestLink

Tags: testing, testcase, testlink, test-plan, test-project

Where should I press to add a new test case in TestLink?

[image]

I navigated to "Add/Remove Test Cases" area, but there is no such buttons.
Help me to get a rid of bad TestLink usability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the test cases definitions/descriptions in "Test Specification" for your "test project". Then in the "add/remove test" page, you will see the list of your test and you will be able to add them to your current campaign.

Answer (score 0):

Go in Test Specification window. Now click on the Test suite in the navigator tree which is in Left side of the screen. Now the Test Suite will open in main window. See the settings button above name of the test suite. Click on it & TA DA...Magic! ;) There are various options among which 1 is to Add Test cases.